# ¿Cómo utilizar async/await en una solicitud ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

estoy tratando de hacer una solicitud ajax con async/await pero me está marcando el siguiente error *await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules*, sinceramente no sé por qué ocurre esto espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, dejo el código.

```
async function SignIn() {
    formElement.validate();
    if (formElement.valid()) {
        const result = await AjaxSignInRequest();
        console.log(result);
    }
}
async function AjaxSignInRequest() {
    let result;

    try {
        result = await $.ajax({
            url: baseControllerUrl + "SignIn",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formElement.serialize()
        });

        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te falta utilizar `async` en tu funcion `SignIn`, ya que estas usando `await` dentro de esa funcion

Comment: Ah vale, tienes razón, pero igual sigue sin funcionar, ya edité la pregunta

Comment: Depende de donde quieres ejecutar el await(o sea desde donde llamas estas funciones) porque si esta función no es asíncrona tienes que llamarlo como promesa o sea con `.then()`

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ya lo corregí, muchas gracias, de hecho se solucionó poniendo el async a la primera función, solo que cuando lo probé no me dio pero por otra razón, te agradezco mucho

Comment: Ajax ya es asíncrono, por qué quieres usarlo con async?